# How to get more then one letter queries back in sqlite3 python?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I am making a program where you can search if something is in an sqlite3 database.

```
def search():
tk = Tk()
tk.geometry('500x500')
def create():
    gette = entt.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('friend.db')
    with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Photos WHERE name1=?', gette)
    conn.commit()
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
```

The program only works when I search 1 letter things. When I try something else, it says that there is incorrect number of binding supplies. It also says that the current statement uses 1, while there is how many letters I gave supplied. If anyone knows how to fix this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `entt.get()` doing?  Your statement looks fine, and if you pass a string as `gette`, it should bind that string to your SQL query.

Comment: entt.get() is taking whats in the entry (the entries name is entt)

Comment: But is it a single value like a string, or a tuple or list of values?

Comment: I don't know. How would I check that? Sorry I am fairly new to programming.

Comment: Please provide us with the result of `print(result)`. It's most likely the text that is displayed in the console or terminal.

Comment: @JamalTheCoolKid, you could check that by doing `print(entt.get())`.

Comment: An error shows up if I put more then one character in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cursor.execute() method expects a sequence as second parameter. You are supplying a string which happens to be 8 characters long.

Use the following form instead:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Photos WHERE name1=?', [gette])
```